# Bootstrap tooltip not working in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I am trying to use tooltip in a react app but I am not able to use that it is not showing proper tooltip. I am using vanilla Bootstrap.
I have written this script tag in index.html file to import tooltip.

```
<script>
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
</scrpt>
```

Here is the code which I have written in my TextForm.js file all elements of this file are successfully exported.

```
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-secondary"
          data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
          data-bs-placement="top"
          title="Tooltip on top"
        >
          Tooltip on top
        </button>
```

Comment: It would be useful to explain what happens when the tooltip should appear. Also if you put a breakpoint in your code does it run and if so is it run across the correct elements?

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version. Are you using raw Bootstrap and not React-Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using Bootstrap 5. An alternative approach is to:

1. Install bootstrap to your project `yarn add bootstrap` or `npm install bootstrap`
2. You should now be able to import the module into TextForm.js like `import { Tooltip } from "bootstrap";`
3. Then create a `useEffect()` and add your code inside it.

Here's some reading on useEffect(), https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html, I hope this helps you.